# Prove : for every integer $n\ge1$, if the regular $n^2$-gon is constructible, then $n$ has no odd prime divisors.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-construction

For every integer $n\ge1$, if the regular $n^2$-gon is constructible, then $n$ has no odd prime divisors.

I know is has something to do with the fact the output Euler's Totient function on $n^2$ needs to be a power of $2$ for $n^2$ to be constructible.  I works up through $81=9^2$ as far as I can tell, but I can figure out how to nail down a proof.

Comment: $p^2\mid m\implies p\mid \phi(m)$.

Comment: I am not sure how to prove what you just put, but let's role with that.  So if we consider a prime p, and $p^2$ divides $r^2$, then p must divide phi(r)=$2^t$ for some natural number t.  This would not be possible if p was odd?  Does it even matter that we were using squared r in the first place?

Comment: Yes, it does matter. For example with $p=3,5,7,17,257,65537$ we have $\phi(p)=2^t$ for some $t$. Actually no other $p$ with the property are known (and none may exist). Are you familiar with the formula for $\phi(m)$ in terms of the prime factorization of $m$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so where I am getting stuck is the following.  So I assume for the sake of contradiction that n has an odd prime factor, call it p.  so if our $n^2$-gon is constructable, $\phi($n^2$)$ = $2^t$ for natural number t.  So the property you gave seems to sort flipped.  Like, in this case we would want $p^2$ divides n implies p divides $\phi(n)$.  Is that guaranteed?  In the sense that do we know our $p^2$ would divide n?  $n^2$ surely, but not sure about n

Comment: I think I got it, but I absolutely fail at typing the math correctly so it will be a little bit.  You are right, the trick is to use the prime factorization of m and write the phi function as it acts on those factors.  That is why the squaring of n matters so much.

Answer (score 0):

By the [Gauss-Wantzel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon#Detailed_results_by_Gauss.27_theory), a regular $k$-gon is constructable if and only if $k$ is a product of a power of $2$ and zero-or-more distinct Fermat primes. If $n$ has any Fermat prime divisors then $k=n^2$ has two identical Fermat prime divisors and hence the $n^2$-gon is not constructable. If $n$ has any odd prime divisor that is not a Fermat prime then $n^2$ has that same odd non-Fermat prime divisor hence the $n^2$-gon is not constructable. Taken backwards, this means if the $n^2$-gon is constructable then $n$ has no odd prime divisors, Fermat or non-Fermat -- hence $n$ is just a power of $2$ and thus has no odd prime divisors.